# LINQ to SQL: Selecting Name (string) by id (smallint)

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I need to retrieve an id's name (`assessment name`)

```
 public int GetAssessmentNo(int AssessmentNo)
        {
            int AssNo = (from a in contxt.View_Assessment
                         where a.id == AssessmentNo
                         select a.AssessmentName);
            return AssNo;
        }
```

Cannot implicitly convert type **System.Linq.IQueryable**' to **int**

Comment: `AssessmentName` is a `string`?

Comment: You want to have the `AssessmentNo` but you select the `AssessmentName` - is that a typo? Because `...Name` sounds like a `string`...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your query returns a set of integers.

Use one of these: First(), Single(), FirstOrDefault(), SingleOrDefault()

```
public int GetAssessmentNo(int AssessmentNo)
{
    int AssNo = (from a in contxt.View_Assessment
                 where a.id == AssessmentNo
                 select a).Single().AssessmentName;
    return AssNo;
}
```

or:

```
public int GetAssessmentNo(int AssessmentNo)
{
    int AssNo = contxt.View_Assessment.Single(a => a.id == AssessmentNo).AssessmentName;
    return AssNo;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Linq defaultly returns group of things, linq doesn't know that your id is uniq.

`(from a in contxt.View_Assessment where a.id == AssessmentNo select a.AssessmentName).First() or FirstOrDefault`.

if you want to receive default value if no proper item is found.

Answer (score 1):

```
public string GetAssessmentNo(int AssessmentNo)
{
    string AssNo = (from a in contxt.View_Assessment
                 where a.id == AssessmentNo
                 select a).Single().AssessmentName;
    return AssNo;
}
If you write int Assno you cannot select AssessmentName because it is string datatype.you can change method datatype int to string after this you will get AssessmentName 
Hope it will help you
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     var usersId = contxt.View_Assessment.Where(a=> a.Username == AssessmentName).Select(a => a.Id).FirstOrDefault();
```

This will result with an the user Id as an int .

```
 var usersId = contxt.View_Assessment.Where(a=> a.Id == AssessmentNo).Select(a => a.Name).FirstOrDefault();
```

This will result with a user name as string .

Comment: Even though your answer contains some aspects that are applicable to the question, it would be better if you'd use the OP's code to show how to do it correctly.

Comment: How about that ? nicer ?  @germi

Answer (score 0):

Your code actually returns a list (which probably in your case contains one item). Compiler can not convert a `IQueryable` into an `int`. You can do something like this to resolve the issue,

```
public int GetAssessmentNo(int AssessmentNo)
{
    return contxt.View_Assessment.First(a=> a.id == AssessmentNo).AssessmentName;
}
```

Comment: His code does not return a `List` - it returns an `IQueryable` - that's a difference.